# Webpage update stream image, when broken image

Tags: php, html

Please help.
The problem is that sometimes webpage can't read the new image due to poor network connection speed and throws broken image. Would it be possible to add that in the case of a broken image, the previous image would be shown?

PHP code

```
<?php
$username='****';
$password='****';
$URL='http://******/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/1/picture';    // 301 - camera 3, stream 1

$ch = curl_init();
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code
curl_close ($ch);
echo $status_code;

if ($status_code == 200)
{
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

    $img = imagecreatefromstring($result);
    imagejpeg($img);
    imagedestroy($img);
}

?>
```

HTML webpage code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <a>
        <img src="kivisilla1camera.php" 
        alt="kivisilla1"
             id="kivisilla1-img"/>
    </a>

</body>
<script language="javascript">
function updateImage() {
   image = document.getElementById("kivisilla1-img");
   image.src = "kivisilla1camera.php" + "?r=" + Math.random();
   setTimeout(updateImage, 4000);
}
updateImage();
</script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #77776D;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the previous image stored anywhere?

Comment: No, but browser should hold it on cache?

Comment: Is it possible to check before webpage image refresh, if new image is available?

Comment: Not really...the act of refreshing it _is_ the check, essentially. I guess you could make a separate additional AJAX request to the same URL just beforehand, but that only proves that the AJAX request succeeded or failed...it doesn't prove that the next one will succeed. If you have an intermittent connection problem, you'll only know if it is going to fail when it actually happens.

Comment: `browser should hold it on cache?`...yes, probably but because you're using a random value in the URL each time, it sees it as a new image and so the cache doesn't come into it. You'd have to keep your own copy of the image in the browser storage I think, and revert to that if you detect a problem.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is load the image to a temporary image, and only swap on success.

If you can imagine this sample HTML which holds a single image:

```html
<div class="image"><img src="https://loremflickr.com/640/360" alt=""/></div>
```

And then this JavaScript, after 5 seconds will replace the image with a new one if the image can be successfully downloaded:

```js
window
  .setTimeout(
  () => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = 'https://placehold.co/600x400';
    img.addEventListener(
      'load',
      () => {
        document.querySelector('.image img').src = img.src;
      }
    );
  },
  5000
);
```

The timeout isn't necessary, it is just for demo purposes.

You can also access the error object for a failure, and using this method you could enforce a maximum amount of time before giving up.

Demo: https://codepen.io/cjhaas/pen/gOQqoEV